# How to get the Max() values index cell position in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to find which number has the most divisors (factors) in a Range of 1,2....n.
For example, if the input is 7, the answer must be 6, because in the range of `1,2,3,4,5,6,7` the 6 has the most divisors.

I tried to print out the numbers from 1 To `n` in the first row, and in the second row successfully print out the number of divisors each number has.

I thought if I had the `Max()` value, I just refer to its cell, and activate the cell 1 row above, which should contain the number which has the most divisors, but I cannot find a way to do it unfortunately.

I'm pretty new to visual basic, asking for your help!

Code:

```vb
Sub mostDivisorsIndex(n As Integer)
    o = 1
    c = 0
    
    For i = 1 To n
        Cells(1, o).Value = i
        
        For j = 1 To i
            If i Mod j = 0 Then
                c = c + 1
                Cells(2, o).Value = c
            End If
        Next j
    
        o = o + 1
        c = 0
    Next i
    
    Dim mval As Long
    mval = 0
    
    mval = WorksheetFunction.Max(Rows(2))
    
    '????
    '???
    '??
    '?
End Sub
```

Comment: Use MAX() to find the highest value. Then use MATCH() to find its location. In VBA you may prefer `Find` over worksheet function MATCH(). In either case you would probably need to provide for a tie breaker. Either MATCH() or `Find` will find only the first match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine the maximum as you encounter it in the loop.

```vb
Sub mostDivisorsIndex(n As Long)
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, c As Long
    Dim count() As Long, maxcol As Long, msg As String
    ReDim count(n)

    maxcol = 1
    For i = 1 To n
        c = 0
        For j = 1 To i
            If i Mod j = 0 Then
                c = c + 1
                Cells(c + 3, i) = j
            End If
        Next j
        Cells(1, i).Value = i
        Cells(2, i).Value = c
        count(i) = c
        If count(i) > count(maxcol) Then maxcol = i
    Next i

    For i = 1 To n
        If count(i) = count(maxcol) Then
            Cells(1, i).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            msg = msg & " " & i
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox "Max Column(s) : " & msg

End Sub
```